# Lightbox_me.js change place of dynamically careated input controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding some dynamic input controls via Jquery, I append them in the form, its working fine.
But these input controls are part of popup which I show using LightBox_me.js and when ever I open the hidden div with lihgtbox_me.js it puts these controls at the end of body tag and out of the form. Due to which data in these input controls are not being submitted with from.
Here is the html

```
<div id="attach" style="display:none" class="srpopup">
  <input type="text" name="attach_name" id="sr1_name" />
  <input type="text" name="attach_serial" id="sr1_serial" />
</div>
```

here is how i am showing the div as popup using lightbox_me.js

```
function showAttachment(){
$('#attach').lightbox_me({
centered: true, 
 onLoad: function() { 
 }
 });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. Any way I can't figure out where is your form start! Try to push your form inside the hidden div like below.

```
   <div id="attach" style="display:none" class="srpopup">
    <form>
          <input type="text" name="attach_name" id="sr1_name" />
          <input type="text" name="attach_serial" id="sr1_serial" />
    </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: basically form contains almost 30 inputs, if user want to attach these two fields, attach div is created dynamically via jquery using $("mainform").append(attachDiv) and it works fine utill I show this div via lightbox_me

Comment: Yes, so try to wrap your form by popup div, like above